# adding array to linkedList

Tags: java

im getting  `uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.` error when adding array to linkedlist

Here is my work

```
LinkedList main_list = new LinkedList();
int arr = new int[2]
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;

main_list.add(arr);
```

Comment: just state what is going to be into the list: `LinkedList<int[]> main_list = new LinkedList<>()` (*or* ignore the warning)

Comment: Do you want to put an `int[]` into the List or all `int` from that array separately?

Comment: @toy moy, please accept the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55215326/3048967). I hope that you find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler warning messages convey that the operation you are trying to is unsafe!

This comes up in Java 5 and later if you're using collections without type specifiers. (See [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) )

Here you are creating a `LinkedList()` without specifying its type. It means that the compiler can't check that you're using the collection in a type-safe way, using generics.

You should create it like below by specifying its type.

```
LinkedList<int[]>  myList = new LinkedList<>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a list of Interger arrays:

```
LinkedList <int[]> main_list = new LinkedList <>();
int[] arr = {0,1};
int[] arr2 = {2,3};

main_list.add(arr);
main_list.add(arr2);
```

with this structure all of your Integer arrays will keep their initial boundaries and the result will not be stored in a long flat list. You can access them independently for later use.

Answer (score 0):

First convert Array into list and then add it into list. If your Arrays only contain `Integers` then you create Integer List and array of Integers. Like

```
Integer[] arr = new Integer[2];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;

List<Integer> main_list = new LinkedList<>();

main_list.add(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

It will work. Or if you  want to save array at every index of lined list then you have to create list of arrays of 
Integers. Like

```
List<Integer[]> main_list = new LinkedList<>();
Integer[] arr = new Integer[2];
arr[0] = 0;
arr[1] = 1;
main_list.add(arr);
```

Comment: I cant do that as im going to add more array to the list and that will mix the elements with a different array elements

Comment: is there a way to add the array as it is?

Comment: @toymoy see my updated answer. when yo add more arrays it will not mix the elements. It will append  all array elemets to the previos elements

Comment: an array of int should work too. (note: last declaration of `arr` above is missing the `[]`)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger yeah int[] works too .  Thanks for feed back :) updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it directly by using `Arrays.asList(arr)`. You can directly convert Array into list by using `asList()` function. Use the following code:

```
LinkedList main_list = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(arr));
```